# How do I have a program check for errors and then keep looping

Tags: java, file, loops, while-loop

My code reads a file where the file name is typed by the user. If the user types a filename that doesn't exist then it catches the exception and prints file not found. What I've tried to do is get the code to loop if the file name is invalid. However, what happens is that the code keeps on printing out file not found and it won't stop. So what's wrong with my code?

```
public static Scanner readFile(String filename){
    File input = new File(filename);
    Scanner sc = null;
    do {
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(input);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Filename not valid");
        }
    } while (!new File(filename).exists()); 
    return sc;
}
```

None of the answers helped me so maybe I'll try posting the entire code and see if that helps.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Report{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = scanner.next();
        Scanner input = readFile(filename);
        CO2Data[] aDataArray  = null;
        aDataArray = readData(filename);
        String highestvalue = highest(aDataArray);
        String lowestvalue = lowest(aDataArray);
        String highest_road = highest_per_person(aDataArray);
        String lowest_road = lowest_per_person(aDataArray);
        try{
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("Report.txt"));
        output.println("The country with the lowest CO2 emissions is " + lowestvalue);
        output.println("The country with the highest CO2 emissions is " + highestvalue);
        output.println();
        output.println("The country with the lowest per person road emissions is " + lowest_road);
        output.println("The country with the highest per person road emissions is " + highest_road);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Error printing to file");
            System.exit(-1);
            }
        }

    public static Scanner readFile(String filename){
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    File input;
    do {
       input = new File(filename);
        try {
            stdin = new Scanner(input);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Filename not valid. Please try again:");
            filename = stdin.nextLine();
        }
    } while (!input.exists());
    return stdin;
}

    public static CO2Data[] readData(String filename){
    File input = new File(filename);
        Scanner sc = null;
        try{
            sc = new Scanner(input);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Filename not valid");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    String info = sc.nextLine();
    int total = sc.nextInt();
    CO2Data[] arr = new CO2Data[total];
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
        arr[i] = new CO2Data();
        }
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++){ 
        arr[i].setCountry(sc.next());
        arr[i].setTotalCO2(sc.nextDouble());
        arr[i].setRoadCO2(sc.nextDouble());
        arr[i].setCO2PerPerson(sc.nextDouble());
        arr[i].setCarsPerPerson(sc.nextInt());
        }
    return arr;
    }

    public static String highest (CO2Data []  arr2){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    CO2Data highestindex = arr2[0];
    for (int i = 0; i<arr2.length; i++){
        if (arr2[i].getTotalCO2() > highestindex.getTotalCO2()){
            highestindex = arr2[i];
            }
        }
    return highestindex.getCountry();
    }

    public static String lowest (CO2Data [] arr3){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        CO2Data lowestindex = arr3[0];
            for (int i = 0; i<arr3.length; i++){
                if (arr3[i].getTotalCO2() < lowestindex.getTotalCO2()){
                    lowestindex = arr3[i];
                    }
                }
        return lowestindex.getCountry();
        }

            public static String highest_per_person (CO2Data []  arr2){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    CO2Data highestindex = arr2[0];
    for (int i = 0; i<arr2.length; i++){
        if (arr2[i].getRoadCO2() > highestindex.getRoadCO2()){
            highestindex = arr2[i];
            }
        }
    return highestindex.getCountry();
    }

    public static String lowest_per_person (CO2Data [] arr3){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        CO2Data lowestindex = arr3[0];
            for (int i = 0; i<arr3.length; i++){
                if (arr3[i].getRoadCO2() < lowestindex.getRoadCO2()){
                    lowestindex = arr3[i];
                    }
                }
        return lowestindex.getCountry();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not asking for any more input inside the loop, and you're never assigning `filename` anything other than the argument passed into the function.

Comment: All your loop is doing is rechecking the same file name over and over.

Comment: I knew that but the problem is I don't know how to make the code check for another file.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When the filename is invalid, you should get a new filename from the user, instead of just re-checking the same filename over and over again. E.g.:

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
File input = new File(filename);
Scanner sc = null;
do {
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(input);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Filename not valid. Please try again:");
        filename = stdin.readLine();
    }
} while (!new File(filename).exists());
```

Comment: I have a problem with that method. If I enter a wrong filename and then enter a right filename the program doesn't recognize the right filename and then in another method in my program it can't recognize the file. The method is supposed to return sc so when I return sc using your code what happens to sc?

Answer (score 0):

The `readFile(String filename)` receives a `filename` parameter, but if such file doesn't exist, what can the method do? It surely cannot invent a correct filename by itself.
So the problem is outside of this method. You need to make sure that this method is called with a valid filename.

```
public Scanner getScanner() {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        String path = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter path to input file: ");
            path = stdin.nextLine();
            return getScanner(path);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("No such file: " + path);
        }
    }
}

private Scanner getScanner(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return new Scanner(new File(path));
}
```